# Issues making an executable with g77 on windows cygwin

Tags: cygwin, fortran, g77

I am having problems getting g77 to produce an executable file that will run on cygwin in MS Windows.  The compiler produces a PE32 executable for MS Windows, but when I try to run the program I get a `cannot execute binary file` error.

Running MS windows 7 on an Intel i7 cpu with cygwin 1.7.15 and compiling with g77 under gcc version 3.4.4.

Comment: g77 is no longer supported.  I suggest trying gfortran; it can compile FORTRAN 77 programs.

Comment: I have tried using gfortran with the same results.

Comment: Do you get this when you run from the bash shell window, a cmd window or when you double click on the filename?

Comment: What happens when you ldd the executable?  Do you get a list of DLLs?

Comment: I am trying to run the program from the bash shell.  ldd only results in an Exec format error without any DLLs.